# flickr api - getting photos with JSONP

Tags: javascript, jsonp, flickr

I have the following script:

```
import "./index.scss";

import jsonp from 'jsonp';

(function() {
    jsonp("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json", (err, data) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})();
```

and I am trying to receive the response from Flickr, and i get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrFeed is not defined

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flickr doesn't support the `callback` query string parameter which standard JSONP APIs use to pick the callback name and hardcodes `jsonFlickrFeed` instead.

You can override the name the `jsonp` client library expects with the `name` option as per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp)